# Выбор алгоритма дерева

Tags: алгоритм, data-structures, дерево

Задача, есть список доменов, относящихся к некоторым категориям, пример:

```
tree.Insert("google.com", 1)
tree.Insert("www.google.com", 2)
tree.Insert("yandex.ru", 3)
tree.Insert("yandex.ru", 4)

tree.Lookup("google.com")      // returns [1]
tree.Lookup("mail.google.com") // returns [1]
tree.Lookup("www.google.com")  // returns [1, 2]
tree.Lookup("yandex.ru")       // returns [3, 4]
```

Категории должны возвращаться в том числе для совпадающих доменов верхнего уровня,
в данном случае "www.google.com" это поддомен "google.com", поэтому список категорий [1, 2].
Вопрос - какую разновидность дерева использовать?
Напрашивается radix tree, но как быть с накладными расходами
на реверс поддоменов при вставке/чтении (www.google.com -> com.google.www)?